# watir-webdriver not working when called

Tags: php, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I have a PHP script that calls a Ruby script (`system('ruby /lib/program.rb')`) that requires watir-webdriver. The system it's on has ruby version

```
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [x86_64-linux]
```

and when I check the error logs I have this message

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir-webdriver (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /lib/program.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Requiring rubygems above does nothing. How can I fix?

See here for output when I run "by hand" and not via PHP's system function:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ad7befc4ca188e7b3989d6d023bcf100

Comment: I have `watir-webdriver (0.9.3)` installed.

Comment: Are you using `rvm`?  Do you have multiple rubies installed?  If so, use `rvm list` to see which versions are installed (and--from there--you can select and set default).

Comment: @orde, `rvm list` outputs the following: `rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p648 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default`

Comment: I don't understand what `/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/` is because I have ruby 2.0, so?

Comment: Does it have something to do with the locations of the script?

Answer (score 0):

`require_relative` may solve requiring package. Try this:

`require_relative 'watir-webdriver'`

Comment: That produces `/lib/program.rb:3:in require_relative': cannot load such file -- /lib/watir-webdriver (LoadError)`

Comment: have you install the 'watir-webdriver' see https://watir.com/installation/

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `system('rvm use 2.0')` before executing the ruby script. That should ensure that the shell is using the correct version for the Ruby execution.

Comment: I already ran `rvm use 2.0` on remote server doesn't that setting stay? And what else would it use if my output for `rvm list` only contains `ruby-2.0.0-p648`?

Comment: The remote server doesn't care about Ruby. If you are executing code on one machine to be run on another, you need to make sure that the originating machine is using the correct version of Ruby. The remote server will only receive JSON wire calls; Ruby does not need to be installed.

Comment: The PHP script calls a Ruby script on the same machine.

Comment: whatever wherever is executing "ruby" should also have an "rvm use 2.0.0" executed right before hand to make sure that the same user in the same shell environment is using the designated version